# Android BottomNavigationBar using ConstraintLayout and ScrollView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am creating a simple app for displaying music & podcast lists horizontally, at the bottom of the screen I want always visible BottomNavigationBar. But without adding an explicit margin on ScrollView, the text of my podcast_list gets hidden, it feels like a hack, is there a nicer and cleaner way how to achieve same result?

Here's my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"> <---- HACK ?

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/podcast_category"
                style="@style/categories"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/podcasts_category_text"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/parent" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/podcast_list"
                style="@style/media_list"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/podcast_category" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead android:layout_marginBottom="64dp" just add android:paddingBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"